# how to add HTTP_CTVFNTUSERNAME in guzzle

Tags: php, phpunit, guzzle

I am trying to create a request in PHPUnit but I am not sure how to pass these variable in the request

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use CCP\Models\Services;
use CCP\Models\ServicesUsers;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class ServicesTest extends TestCase {

    protected $id;
    protected $client;

    protected function setUp(){
        $this->client = new Client([
                'base_uri' => 'http://10.97.109.103:8080',
        ]);
    }

    public function testViewServiceUsers(){
        $response = $this->client->get('/api/user/services/owners/id/269/format/xml',[
                'headers' => [
                        'Accept' => 'application/xml',

                ]
        ]);
        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
        print_r($response->getBody()->getContents());
    }
```

This is giving me error an application error, mentioning is `HTTP_CTVFNTUSERNAME` is missing.

I can see php `SERVER` variable does not have any of these defined.

**update**

```
$response = $this->client->get("/api/user/services/owners/id/{$id}/format/xml",[
                'headers' => [
                        'Accept' => 'application/xml',
                ],
                //'Authorization' => ['Basic '.$credentials]
                'CTVFNTDOMAIN'=>'vf-root',
                'CTVFAPPLICATIONACCESS'=>'ALL,EROOM,IDM,VF_USER,SURVEY',

                'CTVFNTUSERNAME' => 'UddinS2',
        ]);
        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
        $responseXml = \simplexml_load_string($response->getBody()->getContents(), "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        print_r($_SERVER);
        $this->assertEquals('false', (string) $responseXml->header->error, "Error has been found");
        $this->assertEquals(1, (int) $responseXml->body->recordset->metadata->num_rows , "More than number of rows expected");
        $this->assertEquals($id, $responseXml->body->recordset->record->SERVICE_ID, "Record ID does not match");
```

print_r of `$_SERVER` does not show any HTTP_ headers I have set.

```
 Array
(
    [USER] => wwwrun
    [HOME] => /opt/SP/wwwrun/home
    [ORACLE_HOME] => /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index-api.php
    [REQUEST_URI] => /api/user/services/owners/id/4126/format/xml
    [QUERY_STRING] => url=user/services/owners/id/4126/format/xml
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING] => url=user/services/owners/id/4126/format/xml
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /api/user/services/owners/id/4126/format/xml
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 57159
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/httpd/ccp-test/ccp-test.domain.com/docs/index-api.php
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => slswebserver@domain.com
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/SP/httpd/ccp-test/ccp-test.domain.com/docs
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] =>
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/SP/httpd/ccp-test/ccp-test.domain.com/docs
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => x
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [SERVER_ADDR] => x
    [SERVER_NAME] => ccp-test.domain.com
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] =>
    [LD_LIBRARY_PATH] => /opt/SP/apache-2.4/lib
    [PATH] => /opt/SP/php7/bin:/opt/SP/php7/sbin:/opt/SP/php7/bin:/opt/SP/php7/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/opt/networker/bin:/opt/networker/sbin:/opt/VRTSvcs/bin:/opt/VRTS/bin
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => application/xml
    [HTTP_HOST] => x:8080
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => GuzzleHttp/6.2.1 curl/7.29.0 PHP/7.0.17
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
    [PHP_SELF] => /index-api.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1500890812.0252
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1500890812
    [argv] => Array
        (
            [0] => url=user/services/owners/id/4126/format/xml
        )

    [argc] => 1
)
```

Comment: I think it is a good idea to add as well the actual error message you get to the question. In PHP CLI, `$_SERVER` does not contain HTTP header entries (that are often those starthing with `HTTP_`), that just FYI.

Comment: i dont get any php or guzzle errors, its more of an application error check for these headers. if guzzle is using curl, these headers can be set so how can i set it with guzzle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already setting the `Accept` header. Just add any missing ones:

```
$this->client->get('/api/user/services/owners/id/269/format/xml', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/xml',
        'CTVFNTUSERNAME' => 'some username',
    ]
]);
```

Your application mentions `HTTP_CTVFNTUSERNAME` as this is how PHP stores header names in the [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/reserved.variables.server) global variable. The actual header has no `HTTP_` prefix.

Comment: i have tried this but i dont see the header, see update

Comment: Have a look again. Put your headers into the "headers" parameter (just like the Accept header), instead of the outside. 

Is down voting someone who tried to help you really how you want to behave here?

Comment: pressed accidently, and its locked, if you edit answer i can change it